# Flexible LED light strips falling from cabinet

Tags: lighting

I just installed a flexible led light strip and it won't stay in place - it keeps falling down from underneath the cabinet.

Comment: I don't see a question but I assume you want to know how to prevent it from falling. In any case, you've given us very little information. How about the model of the strips, how you mounted then to the cabinet, etc. and maybe some photos would be required for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would look for

- Stronger adhesive or
- Screws and suitable clips

Many LED strips include adhesive tape but fitting clips may also be available.

One reason adhesives fail is insufficient cleaning and preparation of the surface you want to fix something to. Generally you need smooth clean surfaces. Alcohol wipes are sometimes used to remove oily/greasy contamination from surfaces - I have an aerosol can of isopropanol I'd use for this type of problem. You can't use this to cure a contaminated adhesive strip though - you have to replace the adhesive - fitting clips may be a more satisfactory solution.

Comment: I'd use clear silicone for something like this. put it on, tape it up, and then remove the tape after it's sat overnight.